# Adding hover annotations to a Heatmap plotly R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm currently using plotly's heatmap to make a risk matrix (if anyone knows a more efficient way to do it I'd be open to suggestions). Currently I add information about the different risks with annotations but I would like that instead of annotations it was a marker that contains the information when hovering over it, as in the image that I attached below.

Below I attach the code and an image of how I would like it to be.

I'll appreciate any suggestion, advice, etc. Thanks!

```
df.risk <- data.frame(
  Risk = paste0("R",1:5),
  Prob = runif(5),
  Cons = runif(5,1,5))
  
  m <- c(rep(0.1,4),0.5,rep(0.1,2),rep(0.5,3),0.1,rep(0.5,3),0.9,0.1,rep(0.5,2),rep(0.9,2),rep(0.5,2),rep(0.9,3))
  
  scale <- matrix(m, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
  
  pal <- c("#1A9641",
           "#EFE90F",
           "#F44336")
  
  fig <- plot_ly(
    x = seq(1,16,by = 4),
    y = seq(0,1,by = 0.2),
    z = scale,
    type = "heatmap",
    colors = colorRamp(pal))
  
  fig <- fig  %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Cons'),
           yaxis = list(title = 'Prob'))
  
fig %>% 
  add_annotations(y = df.risk$Prob,
                  x = df.risk$Cons,
                  text = df.risk$Risk,
                  showarrow = FALSE) %>% hide_colorbar()
```

[image: Reference]

Comment: Are the `x` and `y` in the plot representative of the probability and severity of the risk? You need to have a way to link the points in the plot to what you want in the hover text. If it does represent these elements of risk, then other than scale, put them in the data frame together. After that, I'm pretty sure I can help.

Comment: Yeah, y=prob =probability and x = cons = severity, the hover text can be the risk column, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you were looking for. I changed your data in `df.risk`, so that the template was a bit more obvious. Other than that the content leading up to the `plot_ly` object remained as you presented it in your question.

The data changes first

```
df.risk <- data.frame(
  Risk = rep(c("Product rendered obsolete",
                "Strict legal requirements",
                "Sufficient human resources",
                "Sufficient material resources",
                "Sufficient manufacturing equipment",
                "Sufficient sales",
                "Reliable suppliers",
                "Unknown/unintended costs exceeding ROI",
                "Evidence technology will work",
                "Sufficient market share long term"), 3),
  Prob = runif(10),
  Cons = runif(10,1,5))
```

Then the initial creation of the `plot_ly` object.

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  x = seq(1,16,by = 4),
  y = seq(0,1,by = 0.2),
  z = scale,
  hoverinfo = "none",
  type = "heatmap",
  colors = colorRamp(pal)) %>% 
  add_markers(
    inherit = F,
    x = ~Cons, y = ~Prob,
    data = df.risk,
    showlegend = F,
    text = ~Risk,
    color = I("white"), # I("transparent") or whatever color you prefer
    hovertemplate = paste0("%{text}<br><br>", # risks
                           "Probability: %{y:.0%}<br>", # prob % rounded
                           "Severity: %{x:.2f}", # severity, rounded
                           "<extra></extra>")) # no trace info

fig  %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Consequences/Severity'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Probability')) %>% hide_colorbar()
```

This is what it looks like.

[image]
[image]